# SQL Comma separated values dml operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where i get data as a comma separator. For instance data in table is similar to below.

```
EmpID Location Active 
109        2       1     
109        3       1     
109        4       1
```

Now i receive data as EMPID 109, Location (1,2,5). What i need to do is Insert 1,5 as they do not exist in table data, Update 2 as it exists in table. Set 3,4 in table to active 0 as they exist in table data but not exist in data we received. I am trying to do all this in one sql instead of using multiple sql.

Comment: You can do it with [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx).

Comment: MERGE is only a portion of the solution here. Since you are receiving a delimited list of values you will first need to parse or split that into values. Here is a great resource for this step. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Then you can use MERGE to perform the upsert your looking for. But be careful....using MERGE for upserts can cause issues. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/723696/basic-merge-upsert-causing-deadlocks

Answer (score 0):

The challenge seems to be parsing the CSV data.  I took the approach of parsing it with XML and then using a `merge` to handle updating the source table.  In the example below I create a table named `e` and assigned some CSV data to `@CSV`. The code below is a whole working example.

```
-- Just creating a working space
create table e (
  EmpID int,
  Location int,
  Active int
  )

insert e values (109, 2, 1), (109, 3, 1), (109, 4, 1)
declare @csv varchar(100) = '1,2,5' -- Assuming everything is nice integer data
select 'Before merge', * from e

merge e as target
using (select distinct e.EmpID
            , m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)') Location
         from (select e.*
                    , cast('<xmlroot><rowdata>' + replace(@csv, ',', '</rowdata><rowdata>') + '</rowdata></xmlroot>' as xml) x
                 from e) e
        cross apply x.nodes('/xmlroot/rowdata') m(n)) as source
   on target.EmpID = source.EmpID and target.Location = source.Location
when matched then
  update set Active = 1
when not matched then
  insert (EmpId, Location, Active)
  values (source.EmpID, source.Location, 1)
when not matched by source then 
  update set Active = 0
;
select 'After merge', * from e
```

Comment: Getting errors at m.n.value and x.nodes in sql editor in ssms. x.nodes as invalid object and m.n.value ambigious column name or missing function name.

Comment: Did you try copying the whole code block first?  (I had run it successfully in SSMS.)  Also, what version of SQL Server are you running?